# 100% Not Working

Tags: html, css

I'm having an issue with the age-old problem of 100% height. I know this problem is asked a lot, and I have reviewed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6879110/setting-height-100-not-working), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19085370/100-height-for-background-not-working-despite-html-and-body-height-100), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17729032/css-width-100-no-working) and countless more. I want to create a basic fixed header, side navigation and main article area, that looks like this:

[image: how it should look]

But, for some reason it's looking like the following (I put 200px padding in the blue bar just to have it appear).

[image: how it does look]

My HTML looks like the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head> 
<body>

<header></header>

<section>

<nav></nav>

<article></article>

</section>

</body>
</html>
```

And my CSS looks like this:

```
* { -moz-box-sizing: border-box; background-color: transparent; border: 0 none; color: #000000; list-style: none outside none; margin: 0; outline: medium none; padding: 0; text-decoration: none; }

body, html { height: 100%; } 

header {
  background: #6c6363;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  height: 100px;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
}

section {
  min-height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 100px;
}

nav {
  background-color: #747feb;
  float: left;
  min-height: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 200px;
  width: 150px;
}

article {
  background: #74eb8a;
  margin: 20px 20px 20px 170px;
  min-height: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;
}
```

As you can see, nothing too special. I know that `section` needs 100% height, and so does `body` and `html`. I can position the `nav` and `acticle` absolutely, and make something like this:

[image]

But, in my actual site (I simplified it for this), the side navigation has drop-downs, which will change the navigation height dynamically. This causes the following to happen:

[image]

Absolutely positioned elements won't change the height of the relative wrapper, so I need to float them. However, floating them doesn't make the height become 100%.

I have even made a JSFiddle to show the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/g8VjP/

If anybody can help me out, I'll really appreciate it.

Thank you!

PS: I'm all for using calc() if it works!

**SOLUTION**

I modified Mayank's answer and managed to come up with a solution. I had to add a couple wrappers, but it worked. My HTML now looks like the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head></head> 
<body>

<header></header>

<section>

<nav></nav>

<div class="cell-wrap">
    <div class="table-wrap">
        <article></article>
    </div>
</div>

</section>

</body>

</html>
```

With the key being the `cell-wrap` and `table-wrap`. I have the `nav` is one table-cell and the `.cell-wrap` is another. With the `nav` having a fixed with, the `.cell-wrap` fills in the rest. However, I want spacing around the `article`, so I added `.table-cell` and made that into a table. That then expands and fills the height and width of the `.cell-wrap`. I then add 30px padding to give a space around the `article` (because margins don't work on table-cells) and made the `article` a table cell.

A bit confusing, but it works!

My CSS is as follows:

```
* { -moz-box-sizing: border-box; background-color: transparent; border: 0 none; color: #000000; list-style: none outside none; margin: 0; outline: medium none; padding: 0; text-decoration: none; }

body, html { height: 100%; } 

header {
  background: #6c6363;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  height: 100px;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
}

section {
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  padding-top: 100px;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

nav {
  background-color: #657182;
  display: table-cell;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 150px;
}

.cell-wrap {
  display: table-cell;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.table-wrap {
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 30px;
  width: 100%;
}

article {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
  display: table-cell;
  min-height: 100%;
  padding: 20px 20px 120px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

[Here's the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uydJ2/). Not sure why there's a scroll bar at the bottom though, but it seems fine if you show it just normally in your browser.

Comment: Here's an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/AxEPc/1). [caniuse calc()](http://caniuse.com/calc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`display:table` and `display:tabel-cell` are you friends here mate!! 
Updated your fiddle to slight workarounds and here you go :  [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/logintomyk/g8VjP/7/)

**CSS to modify :**

```
section {
    min-height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 100px;
    display:table;/* addition */
}
article {
    background: #74eb8a;
    margin: 0px 20px 0px 170px;
    min-height: 100%;
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    display:table-cell; /* addition */
 }
```

Additionally i took the liberty to remove the extra `padding` that you have placed inside `article` , insert a `div` or `section` inside `article` and assign padding to it if it works!!

Comment: This didn't work exactly for me, but it did lead me in the right direction to solve my problem. I would have never thought of using tables and table-cells. To me, that just seems so hacky! But it worked! See question for solution.
Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

`height: 100%` means 100% of the containing block's `height`. Your containing block, `section`, does not have a defined `height` (but a `min-height` instead). You can either:

1. Change `min-height: 100%` on `section` to `height: 100%`. or...
2. Keep `min-height: 100%` and add a `height: 1px` (or anything less than 100%) which will be overridden by `min-height`.

The key here is to have a `height` property set on the parent.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
nav {
  background-color: #747feb;
  width: 150px;
  position : absolute;
  top : 100px;
  left : 0;
  bottom : 0;
}

 article {
  background: #74eb8a;
  position: absolute;
  top : 100px;
  left : 150px ; /* nav width*/
  bottom : 0;
  right : 0;
 }
```